# nil class - NoMethod Error, on form submission. Using form_tag in erb, Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

The -Form_html.erb, the routes.rb and the create method in the controller are as below. But on form submission, it gives nil class error the moment I use params[:mail_setting]

```
 routes.rb
-----------
resources :mail_settings

the _form.html.erb
---------
<%= form_tag  '/mail_settings' do %>



    <div class="fieldBlock">
     <%= label_tag :name %>  <%= text_field_tag :name%> </div>

    <div class="fieldBlock">
     <%= label_tag :id%>  <%= text_field_tag :id%> </div>


    <div class="actions fieldBlock">
     <%= submit_tag "Update Settings ", :class => "btn-large btn-success" %>
    </div>


<% end %>
```

The create method in controller:

```
def create


     @mail_setting = MailSetting.find_by_user_id_and_name(current_user.id,     params[:mail_setting][:name])


        if ! @mail_setting.blank?
            @mail_setting.update_attributes(params[:mail_setting])

        else
            @mail_setting = MailSetting.new(params[:mail_setting])
            @mail_setting.save
            render action: "index"
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `params[:mailsetting]` without the underscore. The model is named MailSetting, so I assume that would be right. The NoMethod error means that there is no generated helper method by the name of mail_setting, which, since you already made the model, is probably because it's spelled wrong.

I would recommend not using underscores/dashes when naming your resources anyways since it just confuses the grammar.

Comment: I tried this for accessing name from params hash, i.e., params[:name], but now its inserting null values into the table

Comment: Oh ok, can you go ahead and post the exact error-text it's giving you. Also, what exactly did you name your model when you made it?